# How to use MSYS2/MINGW64 gdb to debug a program built with MSYS2/MINGW64 toolchain but not built from inside the MSYS2 shell

Tags: windows, gdb, mingw-w64, msys2

I built [neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim)  with MSYS2 MINGW64 compiler. It built great. But the build script forces me to build it from a normal shell (cmd/pwsh).

```
# These are native MinGW builds, but they use the toolchain inside
# MSYS2, this allows using all the dependencies and tools available
# in MSYS2, but we cannot build inside the MSYS2 shell.
```

And since it was built from outside the MSYS2 shell, the debug info in the executable is set to native Windows filesystem, e.g. `F:\projects\neovim\`. So, now when I invoke gdb from inside MSYS2 shell, most things work perfectly, except the source-code listing. The `list` command tells me the filename and linenumber but not the actual code.

I ran gdb from a native shell (pwsh), from the MSYS2/MINGW64 bin directory, and from there I can see the source-code listing. So I'm almost certain the problem is MSYS2 using unix filesytem, e.g. `/f/projects/neovim`.

For some personal reasons, I have to use the gdb from MSYS2 shell. I cannot use the gdb from the native Windows shell. Native shell doesn't work well with my gdb config, which was built for my Linux environment and uses [gef](https://gef.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

So, is there a way I can set the source-code directory to Windows-style in MSYS2 for a session? Or maybe I can set the source-code directory to MSYS2-style when building the project?

Comment: GDB was installed from `mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb` package, not `gdb`, right? Can you confirm that you're using the same GDB executable from powershell and from msys2 terminal?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, you may be right. I was using gdb from normal MSYS2 shell. I should've used it from MINGW64 shell. It has some other irrelevant problem. Or at least I think it's irrelevant. I'll report back after looking into it. Thank for your perception.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, you were right. I can see the source code if I use the MINGW version of gdb: `mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb`. If you would write an answer explaining the reason, I could accept it. I have intuition on why it happens, but just intuition, no knowledge. Another problem that I was facing. It's unrelated. I'll probably ask about it in MSYS github issues. But in case you know something: I cannot source python module from `~/.gdbinit` in MINGW gdb. I can do it in MSYS gdb, but not in MINGW one. The gdb's python setup doesn't find `python3`, even though it's there. Both in MSYS2 and in MINGW.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to write a full answer. [This](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) could help. The MSYS GDB uses Cygwin (or rather MSYS2's fork of it), so it works almost as if it was on Linux. It's no surprise that windows paths weren't understood. MINGW64 GDB, otoh, is a native windows app (just compiled with gcc), so it has full support for windows paths. Regarding gdbinit, do you have `mingw-w64-x86_64-python3.9` installed?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes, it's installed. [Here is the bugreport I filed](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/9735).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU has cross-platform toolchains. You can use those to (kind of) build and debug programs for other platforms. For simplicity, we'll concern ourselves only with gcc and gdb.

Both gcc and gdb has cross platform versions, so you can be on Linux/Windows and compile C programs for Windows/Linux. These GNU tools have compilation arguments called `host` and `target`. So you can compile gcc/gdb to run on Windows system and compile/debug programs for Linux system.

The mingw64 gdb has both `target` and `host` set up to be x86_64-w64-mingw32. So it runs on Windows system and debugs programs compiled by Mingw-w64 toolchain.

The Msys2 gdb, on the other hand, has target and host set up to be x86_64-pc-msys. So it'll only run on msys systems, which means you'll have to invoke it from inside the Msys2 shell (Otherwise it won't find the `cygwin.dll` and won't perform properly, if it does at all). Moreover, it can only debug programs compiled for msys systems.

In short, to debug programs compiled by Mingw-w64 toolchain, use the mingw64 gdb.